# XMLHttpRequest behind a proxy

Tags: javascript, rest, proxy, xmlhttprequest

I want to make REST api requests from javascript.

I have the code:

var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    // XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4
    console.log('on ready state ch %d', this.readyState);
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            console.log("Res: %s", this.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log("Status: %d (%s)", this.status, this.statusText);
        }
    }
    };
req.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com/', true);
req.send(null);
```

I obtain the error:

```
Status: 0 (Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80)
```

I have a proxy and I don't know how to configure XMLHttpRequest  to use that proxy.

Comment: you do not need to explicitly set proxy in code, browser manages proxies

Comment: @MuhammadRamzan — The code says `var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;`. It isn't using a browser's implementation of XHR.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin Got It, Then this Question should be tagged with npm and node.js i think

Comment: @AntonKrylov — "means client was not able to connect to given address" — That's why the OP is asking how to configure a proxy.

Comment: But i want to make this API request on the server side. How can I do that?